# CSS3 translation according to window width

Tags: css, translation, transformation

Simple enough and probably the basics of CSS3 but I just don't get it.

I understand how to apply a controlled translation on an element with transform: translate(x,y)  but how can I do if I don't know its origin and destination?

I would like to see the translations on both axes of list items as they reorganize themselves when their container's width is reduced.

Is it even possible with CSS?

```
<style>

ul
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    font-size:0;
    padding:20px;
}

li
{  
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
    height:120px;
    background:blue;
    margin:10px;
    color:#fff;
}

</style>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

PS: jQuery allowed.

http://jsfiddle.net/fu6d3/

Comment: You would have to use positioning rather than transforms...and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: How can I use positioning if I don't know their position (which depends on the user's window width)? And why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: You can position based on percentages BUT you would have to calculate each item's position and add the values in multiple media queries. that's why it's not recommended.

Comment: My website is adaptive (the container has a static width) and the container's width is changed according to the window's width via media-queries already. There is no % used, only various static widths. So what I expect is to see the items move each time the threshold is reached. in between two window width, they can stay still. For the example sake I say that the ul is 100% but in my website, it is a static width...

Comment: So try it. Position each item and then based on the media queries add new positions, then transition those values. It's a cool effect but very few people actually resize their browsers so it'll be wasted on most viewers.

Comment: Well that's the point: there is no position in my media-queries, only various margins between list items. It is the margin that define the position and if there is no space left, the list items will automatically reorganize themselves as soon as there is an overflow (see the jsFiddle). What you are telling me is the concept and I get the concept but in practice I can't achieve it. Are you telling me that the css as it is doesn't allow translations?

Comment: Nope...you can only transition between two set states (with actual numerical values). If you can't define either one, the transition won't work.

Comment: Ok so would there be a way to workaround this and determine the position via jquery and apply a transformation to that calculated source/destination position?

Comment: I suppose you **could** but it's a lot of work for something almost no-one will see. Also, it's not a **transform** as such, it's a **transition** although I can understand the confusion.

Comment: The attention given to details is not the same from one person to another. For me it's important. I would have liked a less theoretical and opinion based answer but thank you anyway (I flagged your answers as relevant to the question).